# How to have the formatter wrap code with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm not able to format my code in IntelliJ.

I can see the margin line (by default at 120 columns) but it seems that the activation from the menu:

> Code -> Reformat Code

is just ignoring this margin.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Do you mean that the formatter does not break long lines?
Then please check:

> Settings / Project Settings / Code Style / **Wrapping**

**Update:**
In later versions of IntelliJ, the option can be found under:

> Settings / Editor / **Code Style**

There select `Wrap when typing reaches right margin`.

Comment: this option is not there anymore, using version 13.0.2, and the problem remains..

Comment: @ipolevoy the option name is "Ensure right margin is not exceeded"

Comment: The "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" option is in File / Settings / Editor / Code Style / Java / Wrapping and Braces / Keep when reformatting

Comment: these guys keep on renaming setting keys all the time

Comment: This is correct, but in new versions, additional options were added to provide finer control about what can be wrapped. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157389/1104581 for the correct current answer.

Answer (score 207):

### IntelliJ IDEA 14, 15, 2016 & 2017

#### Format existing code

1. **Ensure right margin is not exceeded**

   File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Ensure right margin is not exceeded

   [image: File Settings]
   [image: Ensure right margin]
2. **Reformat code**

   Code > Reformat code...

   [image: Reformat code]

   or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

   [image: warning] If you have something like this:

   ```
   thisLineIsVeryLongAndWillBeChanged();   // comment
   ```

   it will be converted to

   ```
   thisLineIsVeryLongAndWillBeChanged();   
   // comment
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   // comment  
   thisLineIsVeryLongAndWillBeChanged();
   ```

   This is why I select pieces of code before reformatting if the code looks like in the previous example.

#### Wrap when typing reaches right margin

- **IntelliJ IDEA 14**: File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Wrap when typing reaches right margin

  [image: Wrap when typing]
- **IntelliJ IDEA 15, 2016 & 2017**: File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Wrap on typing

  [image: Wrap on typing]

Comment: Yes! This is the actual answer, thank you so much! The point is that the `Wrap when typing reaches right margin` will get in tremendous trouble once you change something on a line that has already been wrapped. Your answer just cleans upon invocation. Combined with a "save and format" macro this is pure gold!

Comment: I would like to add one keyword here, which is what one may be looking for: this is what it is called a **hard wrap** (as opposed to *soft wrap* -- [see the difference here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319925/difference-between-hard-wrap-and-soft-wrap)).

Comment: Also: No guidance for 2018.1

Comment: format code did it for me. This step should be automatic

Comment: still the working solution in 2023 :P

Answer (score 24):

Enabling "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" doesn't work for me in Intellij IDEA 2018.2. I have found the workaround, we need to change every elements below from "Do not wrap" to "Wrap if long".

[image]
[image]

After that, we can preview what kind of wrap type will be changed by looking into right panel. If we are satisfied, Click "OK" or "Apply" to apply the changes. Finally we need a mannual format by using  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> in Windows and <kbd>Command</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> in MacOS.

Comment: This was also the problem for me. If that checkbox is set but the rest is left to default IntelliJ tries to wrap lines, but can't because everything is set to "Do not wrap".

Comment: it is working for me now, in 2023 :D

Answer (score 12):

Or you can use the shortcut:

> **Ctrl + Alt + L**

Comment: Could you post this action's name (Settings -> Keymap)? On most Linuxes the CTRL+ALT+L combination is used to block the computer. I can't even use the "Find action by shortcut".

Comment: @tomrozb this shortcut is for Code -> Reformat Code.

Comment: That locks my screen.

Comment: Only this worked for me on Mac (Cmd + Option + L). None if the checking on boxes in Code Style did.

Answer (score 8):

In order to wrap text in the code editor in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 community follow these steps:

```
Ctrl + Shift + "A" OR Help -> Find Action
Enter: "wrap" into the text box
Toggle: View | Active Editor Soft-Wrap "ON"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the latest IntelliJ, version 2020, we have an option called `soft-wrap these files`:

> Settings > Editor > General > soft-wrap these files.

Check this option and add the type of files you would like to apply the wrapping to.

[image: soft wrap intellij option]

Related question on JetBrains' IDEs Support Forum: [Wrap code to indent](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000013940-Wrap-code-to-indent)

Comment: Isn't this the same what Noah G. [already proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61671703/5730279) via shortcut __Find Action__ (CRTL + SHIFT + A) `View | Active Editor Soft-Wrap "ON"` ?

Comment: Seems they [existed already in earlier versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890852/soft-wraps-in-intellij#49890958): 2019.1.3 and before.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a macro for **Ctrl +Shift + S** (for example) that do all this things:

Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording (the recording will start). Click where you need.

For example:

```
Code > Reformat Code
Code > Auto-Indent Lines
Code > Optimize Imports
Code > Rearrange Code
File > Save All
... (all that you want)
```

Then, click on red button in bottom-right of the IDE to stop the Macro recording.

Set a macro name.

Go to File > Settings > Macros > **YOUR MACRO NAME**.

Right Click > Add Keyboard Shortcut, and type Ctrl + Shift + S.

Comment: This is a basic IDE feature. Macros are OTT and too complicated for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

**For those using intellij 2023 version IDEs**

I wanted to have *all* my files soft wrapped, so I did:

`Settings -> Editor -> General`

Then, in the `Soft Wraps` section a checked **Soft-wrap these files**. Then I added a wildcard for all files by prepending `*.*` to the current value in the textbox:

[image: soft-wrap all files configuration]

Worked for me in goland 2023