# Can you customize how IntelliJ does auto format line wrapping on method declarations and method calls?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In this [**`answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837959/how-to-have-the-formatter-wrap-code-with-intellij/29922077#29922077)

It shows you how to enable auto line wrapping in IntelliJ.

But can you customize it further?

For example, if you auto format this with a line wrap value of 120:

```
public void someMethodWithLotsOfArguments(int thisIsValue1, int thisIsValue2, int thisIsValue3, int thisIsValue4asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf, Double thisIsValue, int thisIsValue6, int thisIsValue7) {
```

It will become:

```
  public void someMethodWithLotsOfArguments(int thisIsValue1, int thisIsValue2, int thisIsValue3, int 
      thisIsValue4asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf, Double thisIsValue, int thisIsValue6, int thisIsValue7) {
```

Is there a way to get it to be smarter about this and format it like:

```
public void someMethodWithLotsOfArguments(int thisIsValue1, 
    int thisIsValue2, 
    int thisIsValue3, 
    int thisIsValue4asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf, 
    int thisIsValue5, 
    int thisIsValue6,
    int thisIsValue7) {
```

Or at the very least like:

```
  public void someMethodWithLotsOfArguments(int thisIsValue1, int thisIsValue2, int thisIsValue3, 
      int thisIsValue4asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf, Double thisIsValue, int thisIsValue6, int thisIsValue7) {
```

Something that doesn't break up the parameter type from the parameter name would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back in `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces`

and set `Method declaration parameters` to `Wrap always`

Doing so, method

```
public void someMethodWithLotsOfArguments(int thisIsValue1, int thisIsValue2, int thisIsValue3, int thisIsValue4asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf, Double thisIsValue, int thisIsValue6, int thisIsValue7) {
}
```

Will be formated as following

```
public void someMethodWithLotsOfArguments(int thisIsValue1,
        int thisIsValue2,
        int thisIsValue3,
        int thisIsValue4asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf,
        Double thisIsValue,
        int thisIsValue6,
        int thisIsValue7) {
}
```

Comment: Excellent. It also allows for method call arguments to be aligned this way. works great.