# Soft wraps in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have enabled all the `soft wrap` settings that could be found in Intellij (2017.3):

[image]

The `Appearance|General` agrees with that list:

[image]
I had hit "apply" - which typically actually *does* work for immediately viewing the effects - and also `OK` on the `Settings` dialog.. but to no avail / no difference / still no wrapping. I have tried several times.

This is a bit challenging with very long code lines. Thoughts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You've picked the right option (`File | Settings | Editor | General | Use soft wraps in editor`).

[Edit: As of IntelliJ v. 2019.1.3, possibly earlier, the options are now: `(File | Settings | Editor | General | Soft-wrap files)`, with a list of filename extensions that should be soft-wrapped by default.

[image]
]

As it said in documentation:

> If this checkbox is selected, soft wraps (or word wraps) are used in
>   the editor. The horizontal scroll bar is not normally shown when this
>   option is enabled. However, in certain cases, when a line cannot be
>   "soft-wrapped", the horizontal scroll bar still appears (for example,
>   if a line consists of a single string that is wider than the visible
>   area.)

With the exception described above, when the parameter applied it will wrap the lines in editor

- if they cannot fit on the editor view,
- or if their length bigger than value specified by the `Right margin (columns)` parameter.

In editor the margin displayed as a vertical gray line. It can be specified as `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Right margin (columns)`.

Comment: `if a line consists of a single string that is wider than the visible area.`   **Ding Ding**.  That is *precisely* my case

Comment: I'm using WebStorm 2023.1.4 and this setting never appears to have worked. I have these file types defined: *.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc, *.js, *.jsx, *.test.js, *.ts, *.tsx, *.json. But a file will only wrap if I press shift shift and type "soft wrap". If anyone can think of any way to make the setting work, that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 15):

Soft wrap works all files extension / specify your file extension on JetBrains IDE

Newer Versions:

```
Editor > General > Soft Wraps > (Tick) Soft-wrap files: *
```

**1. Method**

It leads to performance issues when re-open the IDE for it to take effect

```
*
```

[image: Jetbarins IDE Soft Wraps]

**2. Method**

Otherwise, you can define it like this

```
*.php; *.js; *.jsx; *.ts; *tsx; *.md; *.txt; *.json; *.rst; *.adoc; *.kt; *.groovy
```

And you can put a file extension here. Use semicolons (`;`), not commas (`,`).

You can filter on what files you wanna wrap or not.

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to close and re-open the files for it to take effect

Comment: Yeah may be. Otherwise you can define like this *.php; *.js; *.jsx; *.ts; *tsx; *.md; *.txt, *.json; *.rst; *.adoc; *.kt; *.groovy

And you can put file extension here.

Answer (score -1):

Even with the settings set I had to use view -> active editor -> soft wrap