# How do I count the number of displayed lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to count how many lines in the buffer Vim will actually display. Specifically:

I have an xml file with one root element and many child elements of the same type that looks like this

```
<fields>
  <field field="Delegation">
    ...
  </field>
  <field field="Assignment">
    ...
  </field>
     ⋮
</fields>
```

I folded all the field elements to one line, so that it looks something like this:

```
<fields>
+-- 12 lines: <field field="Delegation">
+-- 7 lines: <field field="Assignment">
    ⋮
</fields>
```

The result I would like is to count the number of field elements in the file. Now, I know that I can do this with something like `:g/field field/p` or other vim commands or external programs, etc. But I would like to be able to just glance somewhere to get a rough idea of the information, same as I do with `set number` and `set relativenumber`, without needing to think of commands to run.

It occurred to me that a way to do this might be to get vim to tell me how many "displayed lines" there are in the current window, or which "displayed line" I'm currently on.

From what I can tell, vim doesn't currently support this out of the box. The only reference I came across to something like this was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376822/vim-line-numbers-on-display-lines), where the two answers seem to explicitly say vim can't do this, although it wasn't very clear to me.

Is it the case that vim can't do this, even with some kind of magic plugin? I wouldn't be averse to writing my own if need be, but I don't even know where to begin looking for what I would need to write such a thing.

Again, I know there are hundreds of easy ways to "count the number of child elements of an xml element"; I just want to know roughly which number element I'm on (i.e. #23 of 100) when editing files like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to count yourself the visible lines.
I suspect this should work:

```
fu! VisibleLines(start, end)
let result=0
let i=a:start

while (i <= a:end)
if foldclosed(i) > 0
    let i = foldclosedend(i)+1
    continue
    endif
    let i+=1
    let result += 1
endw
return result
endfu
com! -range VisibleLines :echo VisibleLines(<line1>,<line2>)
```

Comment: Thanks! This - almost - works perfectly. I just needed to increment the result inside the if block, so that I count each folded block as 1 line instead of 0 (since that's what I see, and what counts how many folded tags I have).

Answer (score 0):

My [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) has a function that calculates that. You need to pass it the start and end line number, and it'll return the number of visible, unfolded lines. For example for the current visual selection:

```
:echo ingo#window#dimensions#NetVisibleLines(line("'<"), line("'>"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. 

Is there a good way to get documentation for the individual functions in your library? In this case the function is simple enough to figure out (seems pretty much identical to Christian's function above) but I'm curious to see if other functions in the library might be helpful to me.

I accepted Christian's answer as I think showing the details of how it's done will be helpful to myself and others if we want something more complex.

Comment: @Danwizard208 I try to document them directly in the source code, but the level currently varies. It's more of a support library for my own plugins than meant for public consumption.