# In a CSS grid, is there a minimum width for grid-template-columns: repeat when using auto?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid css layout that renders beautifully into thirds when there are at LEAST 3 items or more

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
```

However when I have less elements the grid loses its tight column width of 33% and if there is one item its almost full width. Is there a minimum column width property that keeps the column width?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax

Comment: Have you tried [**`min-content`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47452362/3597276)?