# How do I make one element in a CSS-Grid not determine the size of all the other elements in the grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have two grids. One is the main layout. The other is a form that uses a grid in that layout:

```css
my-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
    "nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav sch sch sch" 
    "sd sd sd ct ct ct ct ct ct ct ct ct" 
    "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ";
    grid-gap: 0px;
}

/* this is inside the my-grid main layout */
form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(10,1fr) / repeat(4, 1fr);
    padding: .5em;
    min-height:0;
    min-width:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <form>
    <label>label1</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label2</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label3</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label4</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label5</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label6</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label7</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label8</label>
    <input type="text">
    <textarea rows="15">A comment</textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJEeqV

In that form there is a textarea (15 rows), but because it is big, it makes all the other elements big. How do I stop that textarea from making all the other elements in my form grid the same size?

If I only have `display: grid`, only that row with the textarea makes things big. For example, I have a save button next to it and it has grown the size of the textarea.

Is `display:grid` without anything else the "implicit grid"?

I am able to display all correctly without the areas, and I set the `min-height` of my button, but I don't know if this is the "correct" way to do things. This appears to be a normal HTML problem, not grid specific, but I do not know.

I believe this is a classic table row problem. If I substitute my search and use table and row instead of css-grid, I get many more answers that are useful.

Comment: maybe you find answer here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: There are only 882 questions on the CSS-Grid.  Why would I get a downvote?  There aren't many questions to see on this one.  I may have missed one, but the downvotes?

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't provide enough code to reproduce the problem. I normally post a comment asking for such code but, with all due respect, somebody of your stature in this community should already know the importance of adhering to the guidelines and providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it's a common thing with grids if a cell grows the column and the row grows as well, can you include some markup?

Comment: @Michael_B Thank you for commenting.  I thought I gave enough information, but I will look.  I never realized I had any stature to be honest.  I have "residual" votes because I joined back in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

When you set multiple rows or columns to `1fr`, they will resolve to equal lengths. The behavior is explained here: [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Maybe instead of `1fr` you want [**`min-content`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47452362/3597276):

```
form {
  grid-template: repeat(10, min-content) / repeat(4, min-content);
}
```

```css
my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd" "nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav sch sch sch" "sd sd sd ct ct ct ct ct ct ct ct ct" "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ";
  grid-gap: 0px;
}


/* this is inside the my-grid main layout */

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(10, min-content) / repeat(4, min-content);
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <form>
    <label>label1</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label2</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label3</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label4</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label5</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label6</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label7</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>label8</label>
    <input type=" text">
    <textarea rows="15">A comment</textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRvKVd?editors=1100)

Comment: Micheal, when I put display:grid and nothing else, no dimensions, the grid is still created (I can see it in the inspection).  Is that the implicit grid and the browser creating what it thinks I need?  I have forgotten all my HTML table row layout problems from 2000.  I think I need it again.  It is all very similar.

Comment: Yes, it is the implicit grid. But no, it's not the browser creating what it thinks you need. It's just the initial value of `auto` on `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` (which size implicit tracks). Both `auto` and `fr` have similar behavior, as described in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: I updated the Pen so it is more explicit.  I'm not sure I am implementing what you are saying correctly.

Comment: Use [my pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRvKVd?editors=1100). I don't think [your pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELvxwo) is working as you expect since your `type` attributes aren't closed correctly.

Comment: Whoa! Is that the problem? A syntax error? Close the quotes are `type="text"`.

Comment: No because if i use your pen and drag the textarea up top or somewhere else it makes things expand.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the row height is too tall on other rows just because a textarea exists and expands it's own row?

Try this:

```
form {
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
}
```