# How can I set the width and max-width of a CSS Grid Column?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to limit the width of a CSS grid column?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(17.5%, 250px) minmax(31.25%, 480px) auto;
    grid-template-rows: 100vh;
    grid-gap: 0;
}
.menu {
    padding-top: 32px;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #837DB5 0%, #364176 100%);
}
.list-view {
    background-color: #F5F5FC;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="list-view"></div>
  <div class="details"></div>
</div>
```

In the example above it always uses 17.5% width for the menu because:

> "If max is smaller than min, then max is ignored and the function is
>   treated as min."

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

What I want is a menu that is 17.5% width with a max of 250px. Is that possible?

Comment: If i understood correctly you want the width to grow with screen hence the percentage value, but be fixed at 250px when the screen is smaller ?

Comment: No I guess the other way around. I want it to be 17,5%, but be fixed at 250px when the screen is bigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this might be declare:

```
.container {grid-template-columns: 250px 480px auto;}
```

as your standard rule.

Then, after considering the narrowest width you would like to apply to your third column, you can apply a `@media` query.

Let's say you want to ensure your third column is no narrower than `100px`.

```
250px + 480px + 100px = 830px
```

So you need to write a `@media` query for `830px`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) {

    .container {grid-template-columns: 17.5% 31.25% auto;}
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 480px auto;
    grid-template-rows: 100vh;
    grid-gap: 0;
}

.menu {
    padding-top: 32px;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #837DB5 0%, #364176 100%);
}

.list-view {
    background-color: #F5F5FC;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    
    .container {grid-template-columns: 17.5% 31.25% auto;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="list-view"></div>
  <div class="details"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I guess that's also possible. Was hoping to find a css-grid only solution.

Comment: If you want the first column width to be `17.5%` of the `<body>` width up until a certain `<body>` width and then always `250px` after that, then a `@media` query is absolutely the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

You want your column to have a standard width of 17.5%, and a maximum width of 250px.

You can't use `grid-template-columns` because the [**`minmax()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-grid-template-columns-minmax) function computes to `min` anytime `max` is less than `min`. This means that 17.5% will override 250px on wider screens.

A clean workaround would be to set `grid-template-columns` to [**`min-content`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47452362/3597276), which shrink-wraps the column to the length of the content. Then set the width parameters on the grid item.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content minmax(31.25%, 480px) auto;
}

.menu {
  width: 17.5%;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

However, the percentage length on the grid item doesn't work in this scenario because the parent reference (the column) is essentially set to a zero width (`min-content`). ([fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a8rnosec/1/)).

Fortunately, in this case, because your container is set to the width of the viewport, you can easily overcome this problem with `vw` units instead.

```
.menu {
  width: 17.5vw;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content minmax(31.25%, 480px) auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 17.5vw;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding-top: 32px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #837DB5 0%, #364176 100%);
}

.list-view {
  background-color: #F5F5FC;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="list-view"></div>
  <div class="details"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a8rnosec/)

Comment: now the 17,5% is actually 17,5% of the column width. So the purple column is now really small.

Comment: Did you run the code snippet? You will actually see 4 columns because the first one is not fully filled with a background color

Comment: And what if the content is not 100% width?

Comment: @klaasjansen in this case you use my answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure if its feasible in this way, but an alternative is to use flexbox instead of CSS grid and you can easily achieve this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu {
  width: 17.5%;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding-top: 32px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #837DB5 0%, #364176 100%);
}

.list-view {
  width: 32.25%;
  max-width: 480px;
  background-color: #F5F5FC;
}

.details {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="list-view"></div>
  <div class="details"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this possible with css-grid? I would think so?

Comment: @klaasjansen actually I didn't find a way with CSS-grid, but let's wait for more people to come ;) you may get more answers

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it's a good fall-back. I'm actually trying to learn css-grid, so that's why I want to use it ;)