# How to make 30 auto-width columns with CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have never used [CSS Grid](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/grid/#section_grid-template-columns-rows) before, so please excuse me if this is a simple question. I need to make a grid that is 30 columns wide - auto-width that adjusts with the browser window or parent div. I've read through the documentation but I can't seem to find code that simply creates x number of auto-width columns. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(30, 1fr);
}
```

That code creates a grid container with 30 columns, each of which has an [equal proportion of the free space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276) on the row. You can also try replacing `1fr` with `auto` (content width) or [`min-content`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47452362/3597276) (the minimum column width after all line breaks are taken).