# Building a Grid System w/CSS Grid - Collapsing Cell Problems

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

### 1

I am building a Grid System using CSS Grid and I am having a bit of difficulty. I have a shrink class that works as it is supposed to, but I would like the rest of the cells(as I call them) to fit the space in css grid. If I set `.cell.shrink` to `grid-column:auto`, is there a way to have the other cells fit the space?

### 2

Also, if you notice the code below, I have a class for `.cell > * {whitespace:nowrap;}`. Without it my links are collapsing. Is there a better way to keep it from collapsing? I just want the cell to fit the content without collapsing. I don't want to set a static value in the `minmax()` function either --- Example of what I **DON'T** want (minmax(100px, 1fr)). Again, I am trying to use css grid for this. I know flexbox just fits to the content. How can I achieve with css grid?

Below is the code I have tried.

CODEPEN LINK

---

https://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/djmwNY

HTML

---

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell medium-3 shrink">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  
    </div>
    <div class="cell medium-3">CellCellCellCellCell</div>
    <div class="cell medium-3">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell medium-3">Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Grid CSS

---

```
.row {
    display:grid;
    grid-gap:120px;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(12, 1fr);
}
```

TRIED CSS

---

```
.shrink {
    grid-column:auto !important;
}

.row {
    max-width:1600px;

    > .cell {

        * {
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.row { grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(auto, 1fr))` ?

Comment: Without `white-space: nowrap` your cells will collapse because of the large `grid-gap: 120px` you have set. That's a fixed length, and will collapse anything in its way that is collapsible. `white-space: nowrap` holds them firm.

Comment: @Michael_B whoops that what meant to be 0 instead of auto

Comment: @Michael_B if I were to set a grid gap of rems or something like that would that fix the issues?

Comment: You had 0. I switched to auto. Checking to see if that's what you needed.

Comment: Try it. Also try percentages.

Comment: @Michael_B that isn't working either. Converted the px to rems and to a percentage and both still make the a links break. :/

Comment: Btw, I see nothing wrong with using `white-space: nowrap`. If it works in your layout, why not use it? It's worked for others: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47452362/3597276

Comment: Ok. I just didn't know if there was a better way to handle it, that was all. I think the white-space:nowrap is the best option in this case.