# What's the meaning of "soft-wrap opportunities"?

Tags: css

In this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), it says that `white-space` specifies whether lines may wrap at soft-wrap opportunities. The doc in my native language missed that sentence and I cannot understand at all. Any help will be appreiated.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319925/difference-between-hard-wrap-and-soft-wrap

Comment: Very basically a text line is wrapped to the next line automatically because it would overflow the container otherwise (soft wrap). A Hard wrap is a wrap actually defined `<br>` or `/n` same as you press Enter in text document to cause a linebreak (hard wrap).